# MongoDB: ***aborting after fassert() failure error during converting a standalone to a replica set

Tags: mongodb, recovery, replicaset

Mongo version: mongo:4.2.6

I'm following manual [Convert a Standalone to a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/) to run MongoDB in Replica Set Mode.

When I trying launch MongoDB with command `mongod --replSet rs0` - I got the next log: *****aborting after fassert() failure**

```
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:06.233+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:06.235+0000 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:06.235+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=8c7762d33a84
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:06.235+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.6
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:06.235+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 20364840b8f1af16917e4c23c1b5f5efd8b352f8
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:06.235+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:06.235+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:06.235+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:06.235+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:06.235+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:06.235+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:06.235+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:06.235+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "*" }, replication: { replSet: "rs0" } }
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:06.237+0000 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty.
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:06.240+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:06.241+0000 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:06.242+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=483M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress],
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:06.737+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1606636446:737260][1:0x7fb7b9e5bb00], txn-recover: Recovering log 548 through 549
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:07.233+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1606636447:233737][1:0x7fb7b9e5bb00], txn-recover: Recovering log 549 through 549
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:07.735+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1606636447:735489][1:0x7fb7b9e5bb00], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 548/256 to 549/256
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:07.739+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1606636447:739240][1:0x7fb7b9e5bb00], txn-recover: Recovering log 548 through 549
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:07.792+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1606636447:792369][1:0x7fb7b9e5bb00], txn-recover: Recovering log 549 through 549
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:07.826+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1606636447:826673][1:0x7fb7b9e5bb00], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: (1598047236, 1)
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:07.849+0000 I  RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(1598047236, 1)
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:07.890+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Starting OplogTruncaterThread local.oplog.rs
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:07.890+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] The size storer reports that the oplog contains 1372748 records totaling to 335339428 bytes
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:07.890+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Sampling the oplog to determine where to place markers for truncation
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:07.901+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Sampling from the oplog between Aug  6 11:40:28:1 and Aug 22 01:00:20:2 to determine where to place markers for truncation
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:07.901+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Taking 24 samples and assuming that each section of oplog contains approximately 554226 records totaling to 135388162 bytes
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:07.992+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Feb 17 12:37:42:1
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:07.992+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Placing a marker at optime Jun 16 13:50:38:524
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:07.992+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger record store oplog processing took 101ms
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:07.995+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Timestamp monitor starting
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:07.997+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:07.997+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:07.997+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:07.997+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:08.057+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.system.replset as collection version: <unsharded>
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:08.074+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Flow Control is enabled on this deployment.
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:08.074+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection admin.system.roles as collection version: <unsharded>
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:08.074+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection admin.system.version as collection version: <unsharded>
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:08.083+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.startup_log as collection version: <unsharded>
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:08.084+0000 I  FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:08.085+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.replset.minvalid as collection version: <unsharded>
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:08.086+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.replset.election as collection version: <unsharded>
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:08.096+0000 I  REPL     [initandlisten] Rollback ID is 1
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:08.096+0000 F  REPL     [initandlisten] This instance has been repaired and may contain modified replicated data that would not match other replica set members. To see your repaired data, start mongod without the --replSet option. When you are finished recovering your data and would like to perform a complete re-sync, please refer to the documentation here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:08.096+0000 F  -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 50923 at src/mongo/db/repl/replication_coordinator_impl.cpp 527
mongodb-hotbot_1    | 2020-11-29T07:54:08.096+0000 F  -        [initandlisten]
mongodb-hotbot_1    |
mongodb-hotbot_1    | ***aborting after fassert() failure
mongodb-hotbot_1    |
mongodb-hotbot_1    |
```

**Here is the message in the end of the log before the aborting process:**

*This instance has been repaired and may contain modified replicated data that would not match other replica set members. To see your repaired data, start mongod without the --replSet option. When you are finished recovering your data and would like to perform a complete re-sync, please refer to the documentation here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/*

So I tried to repair my data by following the next manual [Recover a Standalone after an Unexpected Shutdown](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/)

After that in the end I got the empty file `mongod.lock` in my dbPath directory, as I understand it a signal that recovering was finished successfully.

Then I launch mongodb in standalone mode and everything worked fine, so I gracefully shutdown it then, and double checked that `mongod.lock` file still empty after.

Finally I tried to launch command `mongod --replSet rs0` with empty mongod.lock but again I'm getting the same error and `mongod.lock` file updates with 1 on the first line after...

**Any ideas how can I fix this issue and launch mongo in replica set mode with my data?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here is what I have done to solve the issue**:

1. Launch a repair mongod process with my data directory - `mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair`
2. Launch a standalone mongod with my data directory – `mongod --dbpath /data/db`
3. Make dump – `mongodump --host=localhost --port=27017 --out=/tmp/dumps/1`
4. Connect to db locally via mongo shell and shutdown it gracefully – `mongo "mongodb://localhost:27017/admin"` & `db.shutdownServer()`
5. Run new mongod in RS mode with new clean data directory – `mongod --dbpath /data/db_recovered --replSet rs0`
6. Connect to db locally in RS mode via mongo shell and run commands – `mongo "mongodb://localhost:27017/admin"` & `rs.initiate()` & `db.isMaster()`
7. Restore data from dump – `mongorestore --host=localhost --port=27017 /tmp/dumps/1`
8. Finally I got the mognod running in RS mode with my data

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you performed unclean shutdown of mongod, possibly after it was already running as a RS node, and you got a rollback. At this point the database refuses to start as an RS node since any data rolled back will be lost.

Since you don't have any nodes to resync from, I suggest restoring the standalone data directory that you started with out of a backup (you've taken one, right?) and proceeding with the conversion once again, this time taking care to gracefully shut down mongod until you have an operational replica set with multiple nodes.

Alternatively you can try launching a standalone mongod from this data directory, using mongodump to get a complete data dump, create a new standalone deployment, mongorestore the data into it, then repeat the conversion process to RS node.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I chose the alternative (second one) way that you have suggested. I published action list of my actions based on it in my answer above. Hope it will help someone with similar issue.